# How can I send each row to each another spreadsheet which name is stored in a cell of this row?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google sheet with 9 columns. B column is the actual spreadsheet name where they should be. I tried to read data from "All" spreadsheet and send them to the last row of the spreadsheet named in the second row but I'm getting "Exception: Bad value" messages. The code is stated below :

[image]

```js
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
function onOpen() {
  ui.createMenu('Send')
  .addItem('Send', 'send')
  .addToUi();
};


var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var rangeData = sheet.getDataRange();
var lastRow = rangeData.getLastRow();
var searchRange = sheet.getRange(1,1, lastRow, 9);


function send() {
  var rangeValues = searchRange.getValues();
  for ( i = 1 ; i < lastRow; i++){
      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(rangeValues[i][1]);
      targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 9).setValues(rangeValues[i][9]);
      }
};
```

Could anyone suggest how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your script, the values are retrieved from 9 columns from the column "A" to "I". But at `targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 9).setValues(rangeValues[i][9]);`, you are trying to retrieve the value from the column "J". And, `values` of `setValues(values)` is required to be 2 dimensional array. I think that there might be the reason of your issue in those. For this, I would like to propose the following 2 patterns.

### Pattern 1:

If you want to put the value of each row to each sheet, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 9).setValues(rangeValues[i][9]);
```

#### To:

```
targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 9).setValues([rangeValues[i]]);
```

### Pattern 2:

If you want to put the value of last column (the column "I") to the next row of last row to each sheet, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 9).setValues(rangeValues[i][9]);
```

#### To:

```
targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow()+1, 1).setValue(rangeValues[i][8]);
```

### References:

- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [setValue(value)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue)